# GUIs treat /tmp as a file

Tags: macos

A friend was having trouble using `cp` to copy a disk image (a sparsebundle to be precise). I figured out that the line he was using copied all of the /contents/ (sparsebundles are packages, i.e. directories treated like files in GUIs) to the new directory rather than copying the sparsebundle itself.

I later created a sparsebundle on my computer to experiment with `cp` and reproduced the behavior he got. Subsequently, the Finder and Dock began treating `/tmp` like a file. Clicking on the entry I'd made for it in the sidebar would open a Terminal window with `/tmp ; exit;` (which would fail, of course, because `/tmp` is a directory). I could still use the Stack like normal, except for the `Open in Finder` option at the bottom, which would try to execute it.

Curiously enough, I could still open `/tmp` in the Finder by opening a subdirectory and using the `Go > Enclosing Folder` command (<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>up arrow</kbd>). I was also able to access it normally through the command line.

I tried removing and recreating the sidebar entry and Stack, but all that did was cause the Dock to show it as a file and try to execute it immediately when I clicked on it. I then tried rebooting to clear it out; it did seem to be cleared as normal, but that didn't affect the problem.

Can anyone shed some light on this issue?

---

**UPDATE:** I thought to try `ls -l`, which had an @ at the end of the permissions field. I found that it had a `com.apple.FinderInfo` extended attribute, though my attempts to read it only got me this:

```
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 20 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

Deleting the extended attribute (`xattr -d com.apple.FinderInfo /tmp`, as myself, no elevated priveleges) seems to have fixed this, though from what I can tell from my quick search about it, it might have other, negative consequences (and I'm not sure if there was a `com.apple.FinderInfo` attribute there before...). I would still like an answer as to what might have happened and why I got this behavior.

Comment: Isn't `/tmp` on OS X a symbolic link to `private/tmp`, try updating the path to `/tmp/` (with the extra `/` at the end)

Comment: `xattr -ls /tmp` shows a `40` instead of `20` for me in `com.apple.FinderInfo`.

Comment: @emcconville Yes, it is, but I've always used `/tmp` and it's worked for me up until now. In any case, the Stack and sidebar entry were created by dragging and dropping the folder icon at the top of the Finder window, so they should point to `/private/tmp` anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "20" in the FinderInfo xattr indicates that the bundle bit is set. The bundle bit tells the Finder to display the folder as a file, rather than a folder. I suspect this attribute was copied from the sparsebundle (which is really a folder, but the Finder displays as a simple file). So what you're seeing is more-or-less expected behavior with that flag set.

Comment: Do you have a reference for the `com.apple.FinderInfo` values?

Comment: @Daniel: Sort of. In practice, I ran `xattr -l` on a folder I knew has the bundle bit set. In theory, you can figure it out from the [open source Finder headers](http://opensource.apple.com/source/CarbonHeaders/CarbonHeaders-8A428/Finder.h), especially the FileInfo and FolderInfo structs (which say where the finderFlags are in the overall structure) and the enum that defines `kHasBundle = 0x2000`. BTW, the `40` that should be there is the kIsInvisible flag, which can be set with `sudo chflags -h hidden /tmp`